# Verb for replacing common words with unnecessary jargon?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Some people like to exchange common words for unnecessarily technical jargon. For example,

> Your friend: I partook in ornithological observation
>
> You: You mean you went birdwatching?

Is there a word for what your friend here is doing?

That is, if you asked your friend to stop _______ing, you would be asking them to stop using convoluted wording for no reason.

EDIT: I'm not referring here to the amount of detail, only to the unnecessary substitution of jargon into an otherwise straightforward sentence.

Comment: Stop *sesquipedalianizing*?

Comment: It would be ironic if the name for this action was itself overly technical!

Comment: high-sounding (adj.)

Comment: The popular verb from the question I marked this a duplicate of is *expatiate*.

Comment: Bureaucratese or bureaucrat speak.

Comment: Blinding with science.

Comment: Baffle with bull shit.

Comment: How about obfuscate?

Comment: @JasonBassford I would say, based on the example, it isn't a case of too much detail.  More a case of picking the most obscure synonyms possible without adding any more important information.

Comment: It's a bit slangy, but how about using highfalutin' words?  (If you're looking for a "lowfalutin'" word to describe it...)

Comment: Richard Lanham used the word *Skotison!* to mean purposeful obscurity. http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/skotison.htm

Comment: Once again mods mark a question as duplicate without understanding the distinction between this question and those. A popular activity on Stack Exchange...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jargonize

> v.intr.
>  To talk or write jargon
>  [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jargonized)
>
> 2.(intr)
>   to talk in jargon
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jargonized)
>
> intransitive verb
>  to speak or write jargon
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargonize)
>
> 1.to talk or write jargon or a jargon.
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jargonized)

The definitions I've given are the intransitive versions of the verb, which seems to fit your sentence. These dictionaries all have transitive definitions as well, which go something like:

> 2.to render as jargon; translate into jargon. 
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jargonized) 
>  1 : to make into
>   jargon
>  2 : to express in jargon
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargonize)

I would say "jargonize" itself isn't a very common word, so you may be jargonizing in using it, or maybe not, I don't know. Really nothing is done to the word "jargon" other than adding a very familiar suffixal morpheme to it. We do it all the time, often spontaneously.

You can also find the term dejargonize, sometimes hyphenated, though this isn't found in dictionaries. Well, unless you want to include Wiktionary in the count.

> dejargonize
>   1.(transitive) To free from obscure technical language.
>  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dejargonize)

Answer (score 7):

Obfuscate - verb: render obscure, unclear, or unintelligible

This one seems close

Comment: Is "render obscure, unclear, or unintelligible" your own personal definition, or have you taken it from an authoritative source? If the latter, please [edit] your post to indicate it's not your own words (e.g. add quotation marks), acknowledge the source and preferably add a link. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have an adjective. You might ask your friend to "stop being altiloquent".

"adjective Archaic.
(of language) high-flown or pretentious."

I remembered it from the word of the day a couple of weeks ago:

https://www.dictionary.com/e/word-of-the-day/altiloquent-2019-01-20/

Answer (score 4):

You should ask your friend to stop using **[big words](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big%20word)** and start speaking ordinary language. Here's how the Merriam-Webster Dictionary defines this expression:

> a difficult word used to try to impress someone

Example sentence:

> You don't need to **use big words** to make your point.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous words that aren't verbs that describe this speech.

Adjectives that come to mind include *bombastic*, *grandiloquent*, *pompous*.  Those words can be turned into verbs (*bombasticize*, *grandiloquize*, *pomp*), but as you've said in the comments, in doing so, you yourself would be grandiloquizing.

A plainer request might use a noun form: *Enough with the bombast/grandiloquence/pomposity!*

Comment: I have seen "bombast" itself used as a verb, in a contemporary review of Shakespear.

Answer (score 0):

The sophists did this in antiquity. That is the origin of the word "sophisticated". Its meaning has changed but the old meaning could be useful here.
"please do not use sophisticated language"