# What is a person called who likes to use big words to make others think they are superior?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a person called who uses:

1. Complicated vocabulary when a simple answer would be sufficient?
2. Uses complex vocabulary to make others think they are highly educated
3. Is unnecessarily verbose

Comment: Are you after a single word or a phrase (or either)?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/484248/191178

Comment: Logocompensating.

Answer (score 3):

You could describe the person as ***[grandiloquent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grandiloquent)***:

> *(of a person, their language or writing)* given to using language in a showy way by using an excessive amount of difficult words to impress others; bombastic; turgid